# python3: can't restore the out on console to a file from the program beginning to end& pexpect.EOF issue

Tags: python-3.x, pexpect

Below is my code about using pexpect module achieve SSH logon function.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pexpect
import sys

#use ssh to logon server
user="inteuser"           #username
host="146.11.85.xxx"      #host ip
password="xxxx"           #password
command="ls -l"           #list file on home/user directory
child = pexpect.spawn('ssh -l %s %s %s'%(user, host, command))
child.expect('password:')
child.sendline(password)
childlog = open('prompt.log',"ab")     # restore prompt log to file prompt.log
__console__ = sys.stdout               # make a backup of system output to console 
sys.stdout = childlog                  # print the system output to childlog
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)  
childlog.close() 
sys.stdout = __console__               # back to the original state of system output
print(child.before)                    # print the contents before match expect function
```

after I execute my script

```
[~/Liaohaifeng]$ python3 ssh_test.py
b' \r\ntotal 69636\r\n-rw-rw-r-- 1 inteuser inteuser      949 Nov 28 02:01 
01_eITK_trtest01_CrNwid.log\r\n


[~/Liaohaifeng]$ cat prompt.log

total 69412
-rw-rw-r-- 1 inteuser inteuser      949 Nov 28 02:01 01_eITK_trtest01_CrNwid.log
```

I think this result is not my expected. when I remove the code `child.expect(pexpect.EOF)` in my script, the output about `print(child.before)` can be correct(it should print the content before matching `password`)

Below is the output after I remove `child.expect(pexpect.EOF)`

```
[~/Liaohaifeng]$ python3 ssh_test.py
b"\r\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r\n...
These computer resources are provided for authorized users only. For legal,
\r\n
security and cost reasons, utilization and access of resources are sxx, in\r\n
accordance with approved internal procedures, at any time if IF YOU ARE NOT AN AUTHORIZED USER; PLEASE EXIT IMMEDIATELY...\r\n "
```

my purpose is print out all the output to a file after executing the script,but the log file still only contains the output of listing directory. So why this happen? could you please help update my script? thank you very much.

Comment: What's your purpose?

Comment: sorry for not make my purpose clear, I have update my question ,please review.

Comment: Are you sure there's any output in childlog?

Comment: yes. it is . the output is in prompt.log file, and can you tell me what's your issue ? you need change Linux server information,I make them invisible.

Comment: Not sure which version of pexpect you're using but for me the version 4.2.1 does not output to sys.stdout at all by default.

Comment: [~/Liaohaifeng]$  cygcheck -c | grep pexpect
python2-pexpect                         4.2.1-1                   OK
python3-pexpect                         4.2.1-1                   OK

Comment: hi, does my answer help solve your problem?

Comment: yes, it solved, many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `spawn().logfile_read`.

```
[STEP 101] # cat example.py
import pexpect, sys

child = pexpect.spawn('bash --norc')
if sys.version_info[0] <= 2:
    # python2
    child.logfile_read = open('/tmp/pexpect.log', 'w')
else:
    # python3
    fp = open('/tmp/pexpect.log', 'w')
    child.logfile_read = fp.buffer

child.expect('bash-[.0-9]+[$#] ')

child.sendline('echo hello world')
child.expect('bash-[.0-9]+[$#] ')

child.sendline('exit')
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
child.logfile_read.close()
[STEP 102] # python3 example.py
[STEP 103] # cat /tmp/pexpect.log
bash-4.4# echo hello world
hello world
bash-4.4# exit
exit
[STEP 104] #
```

Comment: when use spawn().logfile_read it won't reflect password information , but use `.logfile` directly it will make password visible.And the file type should be binary file .

Comment: right. `.logfile` applies for both `.logfile_read` and `.logfile_send`.

Comment: it's ok to open in *binary* mode. in my code i open it in *text* mode but assigned the `fp.buffer` to the `.logfile_read` which is the same.

Comment: pexepct with python3 also has a `spawnu` which can directly write to *text* mode files.

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple question, just adjust code order is OK.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pexpect
import sys

#use ssh to logon server
user="inteuser"           #username
host="146.11.85.xxx"      #host ip
password="xxxx"           #password
command="ls -l"           #list file on home/user directory   
child = pexpect.spawn('ssh -l %s %s %s'%(user, host, command))
childlog = open('prompt.log',"ab")
child.logfile = childlog
child.expect('password:')
child.sendline(password)                                  
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)  
childlog.close()
```